# return non array in using map

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I used map to loop but it returned an array, not sure I should use something else like forEach. I have this initial object.

```
data.discounts: [{
    days: 3,
    is_enable: true
},{
    days: 10,
    is_enable: false
}]
```

Then I do the checking on is_enable

```
const newObj = {
    "disableDiscount_3": !isEmpty(data.discounts) ? (data.discounts.map(obj => obj.days === 3 && obj.is_enable === true ? true : false)) : ''
}
```

then it became

```
newObj.disableDiscount_3 = [{
    true,
    false,
    false,
    false
}]
```

What I want is actually just true or false like: `newObj.disableDiscount_3 = true` What should I do?

Comment: Are you expecting a single `Boolean` as result if `obj.days === 3 && obj.is_enable`?

Comment: use `some()` instead of `map()`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map()` method is not meant to be used for that, instead you can use `some()` that will check if specified object exists and return `true/false`.

```js
var discounts = [{
  days: 3,
  is_enable: true
}, {
  days: 10,
  is_enable: false
}]

var check = discounts.some(e => e.days == 3 && e.is_enable === true);
console.log(check)
```

To first find specific object you can use `find()` method and if the object is found then you can take some property.

```js
var data = {
  discounts: [{
    days: 3,
    is_enable: true,
    value: 123
  }, {
    days: 10,
    is_enable: false
  }]
}

var obj = {
  "discount_3": (function() {
    var check = data.discounts.find(e => e.days == 3 && e.is_enable === true)
    return check ? check.value : ''
  })()
}

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: `=== true` is not necessary following `&& e.is_enable`, yes?

Comment: I guess it depends on the OP needs, for example https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1905/

Comment: some is es2015? browsers support ?

Comment: What if I want to return value instead of just true or false? like https://jsfiddle.net/s25qx8q5/

Comment: Take a look at table at bottom of https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some?v=example

Comment: `e.days == 3 && e.is_enable === true` should be equivalent to `e.days == 3 && e.is_enable`

Comment: @AlanJenshen _"What if I want to return value instead of just true or false?"_ That is present Question, yes? What is the expected result? Single `Boolean` or other type of value? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Alan Jenshen  And what is `obj.discount_content`?

Comment: @NenadVracar thanks, that does the job. Why I felt I'm too dated for js? I was using lots of manual stuff like indexOf or foreach loop, nowadays seems everyone is going to newer es2015, or es6 stuff.